# Cannot Iterate over objects in Power Shell

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer

I have a list of buttons on a web page. I am able to get the list of buttons by using the Get Class Name function. But I am not able to iterate over it.

Here is the code:

```html
main role="main">
        <div class="wrapper">

        </div>

        <div class="wrapper wrapper-medium">


  <header>
    <h1>Unsubmitted Timesheets</h1>

    <div class="clearfix">
      <div class="fl-left">
        <select name="" id="select-timeframe" class="hui-input"><option value="/missing_time/period/36/2018">05 Feb 2018 - 11 Feb 2018</option>
<option selected="selected" value="/missing_time/period/29/2018">This Week</option>
<option value="/missing_time/period/22/2018">22 Jan 2018 - 28 Jan 2018</option>
<option value="/missing_time/period/15/2018">15 Jan 2018 - 21 Jan 2018</option>
<option value="/missing_time/period/8/2018">08 Jan 2018 - 14 Jan 2018</option>
<option value="/missing_time/period/29/2018?all_weeks=1">- show all weeks -</option></select>
      </div>

        <div class="fl-right">
          <button type="button" class="hui-button" data-open-dialog="email-reminder-dialog">
              <i data-icon="check-green"></i>
              Sending Reminder Every Friday
          </button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <section>
      <form id="missing-time-form" action="/missing_time/reminders?return_to=%2Fmissing_time%2Fperiod%2F29%2F2018" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="?"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="YmA26BT5bHy1NQKiKks+j/nKl5saFnF2fAmp/Oy6zuWANPkuuMLYTZDtdZHa/7TNh2CcUx5R2e0FsPWOxThVoQ==">
        <table id="unsubmitted-timesheets" class="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th></th>
              <th>
                Team Members<br>
                <small>
                  Select:
                  <button type="button" class="button-link js-toggle-all-users">All</button>
                  /
                  <button type="button" class="button-link js-toggle-no-users">None</button>
                </small>
              </th>
              <th class="text-right">Time</th>
              <th></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody class="has-clickable-table-rows" data-required-checkboxes="You must select at least one recipient.">
              <tr class="clickable-row">
                <td class="col-checkbox">
                  <div class="hui-checkbox">
                    <input name="send_reminder[1964976]" type="hidden" value="0"><input class="checkbox" aria-label="Send Reminder for Alexander Cubillos" type="checkbox" value="1" name="send_reminder[1964976]" id="send_reminder_1964976">
                    <label for="send_reminder_1964976"></label>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  Alexander Cubillos
                    <span class="text-label">Contractor</span>
                  <label for="send_reminder_1964976" class="clickable-row-link"></label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-right">
                  24:00
                  <label for="send_reminder_1964976" class="clickable-row-link"></label>
                </td>
                <td class="col-actions">
                  <a class="hui-button hui-button-tiny" href="/entry/show/29/2018?of_user=1964976">View Timesheet</a>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="clickable-row">
                <td class="col-checkbox">
                  <div class="hui-checkbox">
                    <input name="send_reminder[1840318]" type="hidden" value="0"><input class="checkbox" aria-label="Send Reminder for Allain Dollete" type="checkbox" value="1" name="send_reminder[1840318]" id="send_reminder_1840318">
                    <label for="send_reminder_1840318"></label>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  Allain Dollete
                  <label for="send_reminder_1840318" class="clickable-row-link"></label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-right">
                  24:30
                  <label for="send_reminder_1840318" class="clickable-row-link"></label>
                </td>
                <td class="col-actions">
                  <a class="hui-button hui-button-tiny" href="/entry/show/29/2018?of_user=1840318">View Timesheet</a>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="clickable-row">
                <td class="col-checkbox">
                  <div class="hui-checkbox">
                    <input name="send_reminder[1882520]" type="hidden" value="0"><input class="checkbox" aria-label="Send Reminder for Anil Khemchandani" type="checkbox" value="1" name="send_reminder[1882520]" id="send_reminder_1882520">
                    <label for="send_reminder_1882520"></label>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  Anil Khemchandani
                    <span class="text-label">Contractor</span>
                  <label for="send_reminder_1882520" class="clickable-row-link"></label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-right">
                  0:00
                  <label for="send_reminder_1882520" class="clickable-row-link"></label>
                </td>
                <td class="col-actions">
                  <a class="hui-button hui-button-tiny" href="/entry/show/29/2018?of_user=1882520">View Timesheet</a>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="clickable-row">
                <td class="col-checkbox">
                  <div class="hui-checkbox">
                    <input name="send_reminder[1028098]" type="hidden" value="0"><input class="checkbox" aria-label="Send Reminder for Anna Jhaveri" type="checkbox" value="1" name="send_reminder[1028098]" id="send_reminder_1028098">
                    <label for="send_reminder_1028098"></label>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  Anna Jhaveri
                  <label for="send_reminder_1028098" class="clickable-row-link"></label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-right">
                  0:00
                  <label for="send_reminder_1028098" class="clickable-row-link"></label>
                </td>
                <td class="col-actions">
                  <a class="hui-button hui-button-tiny" href="/entry/show/29/2018?of_user=1028098">View Timesheet</a>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="clickable-row">
                <td class="col-checkbox">
                  <div class="hui-checkbox">
                    <input name="send_reminder[1399194]" type="hidden" value="0"><input class="checkbox" aria-label="Send Reminder for Chaitanya Potluri" type="checkbox" value="1" name="send_reminder[1399194]" id="send_reminder_1399194">
                    <label for="send_reminder_1399194"></label>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  Chaitanya Potluri
                    <span class="text-label">Contractor</span>
                  <label for="send_reminder_1399194" class="clickable-row-link"></label>
                </td>
                <td class="text-right">
                  40:00
                  <label for="send_reminder_1399194" class="clickable-row-link"></label>
                </td>
                <td class="col-actions">
                  <a class="hui-button hui-button-tiny" href="/entry/show/29/2018?of_user=1399194">View Timesheet</a>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="clickable-row">
                <td class="col-checkbox">
                  <div class="hui-checkbox">
                    <input name="send_reminder[1908612]" type="hidden" value="0"><input class="checkbox" aria-label="Send Reminder for Daniel Pedraza Mena" type="checkbox" value="1" name="send_reminder[1908612]" id="send_reminder_1908612">
                    <label for="send_reminder_1908612"></label>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
```

I would Ideally like to click on a button got to the next page perform some action and then go back to the First Page. And then goto the next button. This action should be repeated until all the buttons are visited. I have been wracking my head around it but I have not able to come up with a solution.

I tried doing this, but it only targets the first or last button

```
($ie.Document.GetElementsByClassName("hui-button hui-button-tiny") |
    Select-Object -First 1).Click()

($ie.Document.GetElementsByClassName("hui-button hui-button-tiny") |
    Select-Object -Last 1).Click()
```

If I do something like this-

```
$ViewTimessheetObject=($ie.document.getElementsByClassName("hui-button hui-button-tiny") |Select-Object -first 1)

while($ie.Busy) { Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100 }
($ViewTimesheetObject |  ForEach-Object {$_.Click()})
```

> It throws an error message saying that "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. + ($ViewTimesheetObject |  ForEach-Object {$_.Click()})

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

your foreach should be for `$ie.document.getElementsByClassName`

```
($ie.document.getElementsByClassName("hui-button hui-button-tiny")) | Foreach { $_.Click()}
```